# How to create folder on photo album

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I would like to create folder on photo album.
Is it possible?
I searched AssetsLibrary. But It seems to be impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's impossible to create and delete albums in photo library programmatically.

Comment: Thanks for your confirming it.